# What shape does a rope make when compressed / coiled up?

Tags: potential-energy, curvature, string, continuum-mechanics

Let's say we have a rope placed on the line $y=0$ on a flat table in the $(x,y)$ plane. We place one hand on the rope at $x=0$ and $x=l$ and then move our hands together along the $x$-axis so that they are now at $x=0$ and $x=a$. What shape does the rope make, given a specific $a$ and $l$?

If the rope is perfectly straight, then in our model the rope would just be compressed and we would still have a straight rope. However I am interested in the case when a slight (infinitesimal) bend is present at some point on the rope between $x=0$ and $x=a$ and hence the rope will curve.

---

I can guess at the following constraints / ideas:

$y(0) = y(a) = 0$

$y'(0) = y'(a) = 0$

The arc length $\int_0^a\sqrt{1+y'^2} \ dx = l =$ constant.

Perhaps we could find $y$ by minimising the total "curvature" of $y(x)$ (or some proxy / measure of it) - e.g. $\int_0^a |\frac{dy}{dx}|^2 \ dx$.

Are these ideas going in the right direction? Also, is there a more 'physics' way of solving the problem by e.g. minimising the Potential Energy of the rope?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary

Comment: @ManRow but this problem is independent of gravity? Also a cosh curve doesn't include two distinct points at which the derivative is zero so I can't see how it could be a valid y(x). Am I missing something?

Comment: You asked, *"Are these ideas going in the right direction? Also, is there a more 'physics' way of solving the problem by e.g. minimising the Potential Energy of the rope?"* What is the potential energy you're trying to minimize then, if not gravitational?

Comment: @ManRow The elastic potential energy stored within the bent rope, which I assume increases with the overall "curviness" of the rope.

Comment: Such as an [elastic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastica_theory), with examples [here](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/linteaire/linteaire.shtml) and [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-geometry-and-symmetry-in-physics/volume-17/issue-none/Eulers-Elastica-and-Beyond/10.7546/jgsp-17-2010-45-86.pdf)?

Comment: @ManRow Thank you!

Comment: FYI; The technical term for the way in which the shape of the rope changes is [_buckling_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckling). Engineers have written a lot about how stiffer materials buckle under compression, but I don't know if any of that literature would be helpful in understanding the behavior of a floppy length of rope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is called an elastic curve. The links for their equations and the development of the theory can be found in ManRow's comments.

See also [Elastica Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastica_theory)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).